# How to export the product details in csv format from product view page in magento 1.7?

Tags: magento, csv, magento-1.7, export-to-csv

I want to export all details of product from Magento front-end (product-view-page) in **CSV** format. Actually, I want to display a button on product view page, by clicking on it, details of the that product should be exported. But I am not getting the right idea, please anybody can help me. Suggest me from where to start.

Comment: Plz, anybody ... I'm struck very badly . :(

Comment: Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action, I am extending this class, but it is redirecting me too admin panel. Plz somebody help me.